# Bracket right after a function call in R

Tags: r

```
fixed_length_text<-fread("sample.dat",sep="\n",header=FALSE)[, lapply(1:
(length(col_ends$beg)),function(ii) 
substr(V1,col_ends$beg[ii],col_ends$end[ii]))]
```

The code above is supposed to read a fixed length format text file.

It works well, but what does the brackets right after the function call mean? I know that '[' is a function itself, but I don't understand how the brackets are being used in this code?

Can you please explain to me what the brackets do in the sample code? Thanks.

Comment: It's just acting on the results of `fread`. So it's the same as if you did `temp <- fread(); temp[,...]`. (imho, this is a great example of code that would be much improved, readability-wise, if it were split into multiple lines, maybe even more than two)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the result of `fread` function is most times a data frame so look at it like this

```
fixed_length_text<-fread("sample.dat",sep="\n",header=FALSE)
# fixed_length_text is now a data frame so we can use lapply on it using []
fixed_length_text = fixed_length_text[, lapply(1:
    (length(col_ends$beg)),function(ii) 
    substr(V1,col_ends$beg[ii],col_ends$end[ii]))]
```

Comment: I guess my confusion is how the '[ ]' is being used with 'lapply' function in it. Isn't df[,col] means a column of the data frame? Now instead of a column index, a 'lapply' is placed which will return a list of sub_strings. How does this work? Sorry, I am still an elementary R learner.

Comment: @Xiaolei yes `df[,col]` means a column of the data frame the `lapply` chooses which columns you want from col_ends, it gives  a list of substrings which if they are column names get chosen (I haven's seen the whole code so I'm guessing the substrings are actually column names

Comment: The sample text file is like this "01--ENG--A\n02--CHM--C\n...". It is a sample grade file. The col_ends vector has the beginning (beg) and ending (end) of each part. So the fixed_length_text right after 'fread' is a data frame of each single line (with only one column called 'V1'), then the 'lapply' chops each line into three columns.

Comment: fixed_length_text[, lapply(1:length(col_ends$beg),function(ii) 
    substr(V1,col_ends$beg[ii],col_ends$end[ii]))]                                                     
                                                                                                              is the same as 
                                                                                     
    lapply(1:length(col_ends$beg),function(ii) 
    substr(fixed_length_text$V1,col_ends$beg[ii],col_ends$end[ii]))]

Comment: please see above two comments. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand your question since you've explained the code yourself. as your second comment shows what `lapply` does in the brackets of dataframe. you could separate it from the code to make it readable and understandable more.

Comment: I guess R's readability is my question. Some code is so hard to understand, which frequently made me doubt myself. But I get it now. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: If you have the time, it's good to take a look at [this](https://nicercode.github.io/blog/2013-04-05-why-nice-code/) article